# Why is the verb “asseoir” conjugated in “Restez assises, je vous en prie”?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes, conjugaison

In the following sentence:

> Restez assises, je vous en prie.

In this sentence, the verb should be *rester* and it is in the imperative form, I think.

However, I'm not sure why *assises* is conjugated as well. If it is a verb, I think it should be the infinitive form since it is put after the verb. But in this case, the verb *asseoir* (or *assoir*?) is conjugated.

So why is it happening and what rule is it based on? I think the sentence should be the following:

> Restez asseoir, je vous en prie.

Or maybe:

> Restez s'asseoir, je vous en prie.

Comment: *Stay seat, please* would be as incorrect as *Restez asseoir, je vous en prie*

Comment: @jlliagre In English it's *stay sit*, not *stay seat*. I assume OP confused it with infinitive because all forms are the same but it's not.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Precisely. I intentionally gave an incorrect form. I used the formal "to seat" instead of "to sit" to make clear English, like French, cannot use the infinitive here.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat and the right form would be *Stay seated, please*

Comment: @jlliagre You're right it's either stay sit or stay seated and in latter you clearly see it's not an infinitive

Comment: _Please remain seated_ est probablement meilleur soit dit en passant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing here with the adjective. The construction is a common one from which derive many instances in which it is impossible not to recognise the adjective;

(Il s'agit ici de l'adjectif. On a une construction courante qui donne les formes suivantes dans lesquelles on ne peut pas ne pas reconnaitre l'adjectif ;)

- Restez tranquille !
- Restez vrai !
- Restez gentille !
- Restez poli s'il vous plait !

…

By a check in the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assis) you'll find that the past participle and the adjective have the same spelling.

When the adjective and the past participle have the same form the nature of the word can only be that of past participle in case of the presence of an auxiliary verb or of a passive turn;

(Lorsque l'adjectif et le participe passé ont la même forme il ne peut être question du participe passé qu'en cas de la présence d'un auxiliaire de conjugaison ou d'une tournure passive ;)

example of use where the part of speech is past participle

- Les dames, assises par les messieurs, étaient les premières à prendre place à la table.

Do not confuse « Elle est assise. » (adj.) and « Elle s'est assise. » (part. passé).

Comment: C'est l'adjectif ou bien le participe passé ? Et je pense qu'il faut préciser que le locuteur s'adresse aux dames.

Comment: Je dis bien qu'il s'agit de l'adjectif. L'accord de l'adjectif est un autre sujet ; je présume que cela est compris : le féminin de « assis » est « assise » et s'il y a plusieurs personnes du sexe féminin alors c'est « assises » qu'il faut écrire.

Comment: @Dimitris Comme l'adjectif ici est dérivé du participe passé, la distinction n'est pas trop claire, mais je dirais que oui, la fonction dans cette phrase correspond plus prochement à un adjectif.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Je trouve qu'il faut parler d'un participe à valeur d'adjectif qualificatif (ici). Mais je ne suis qu'un docteur de mécanique:-)!

Comment: @LukeSawczak https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-18225.php

Comment: @LukeSawczak https://wwwling.arts.kuleuven.be/alfagram/Temps/nperso/partpas/femploi.htm

Comment: @Dimitris That first one is not too clear on the distinction — most are arguable, but #11 "l'enfant réfléchi" as a pp? In the other link, (1c) refers to this case by saying les pps "peuvent s'employer adjectivalement"... In that same second link, if you look under (1d) you'll find that it refers to reflexives like *s'asseoir* by saying "le participe est de type adjectif". So that page seems to me to lean towards an adjectival analysis. That said, I hold by my general statement that the distinction is inherently fuzzy, including between "s'employer adjectivalement" and "être de type adjectif" !

Answer (score 1):

> Restez assises, je vous en prie.

In the sentence above ***assises*** is conjugated in the ***participé passé*** (past participle), according to [leconjugeur](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/french/verb/asseoir.html) you can find below the various forms it can take *depending on the subject* :

> assis
>   **assise**
>   assis
>   assises
>   ayant assis

---

So, accordingly we would use « assis » when talking to a man

> Restez **assis**, je vous en prie.

« assise » when talking to a woman:

> Restez **assise**, je vous en prie.

and « assises » when talking to a group of women:

> Restez **assises**, je vous en prie.